# What's the different between "DO" and "Really"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I have two different sentences as follows:

1. I ***do*** love her.
2. I ***really*** love her.

**Question:**
 1. Are `do` and `really` have the same meaning or interpretation?
 2. What *are* both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I really love her*** means you love her a lot. The *really* intensifies the emotion.

***I do love her*** means you do, in fact, love her. The *do* intensifies the verb, and asserts it as fact.

I would expect the "really" version to be used when someone is deeply in love with the other person, and wants to express that fact.

I would expect the "do" would be used in less frequent situations, such as when someone is doubting that person's love:

> Do you even love Jennifer?
>   Yes, I do love her!

although that person might also reply:

> Yes, of course I love her!

Comment: `I would expect the "really" version to be used when someone is deeply in love with the other person, and wants to express that fact. ` is subjective opinion. Okay, do you mean `do` is the highest level to `emphasize` about the real love?

Comment: So, there's another question. How to `emphasize ...` in English. There will be many version and answers, right?

Comment: I mean I can imagine a lot of native speakers saying `really love` in several contexts: _I really love Jennifer, I really love chocolate ice cream, I really love watching football_, etc. On the other hand, I have a harder time imagining native speakers using _do_ instead of _really_ except when the context steers them in that direction. It's grammatical, but it doesn't sound natural. As for `emphasis`, yes, there are many ways to add emphasis: _I really love her, I love her a lot, I love her very much, I love her so much it isn't even funny,_ etc. (That last one is idiomatic slang.)

Comment: Because `really` is commonly used?

Comment: And also because `do` is not commonly used. _I do love chocolate ice cream_ sounds very old-fashioned; _I really love chocolate ice cream_ sounds idiomatic and contemporary.

Comment: Yey! I got it. thanks. But, I have to say to my students that `do` is an adverb  - like `really` since they both have the same way `to emphasize`. Indonesian learners often gets confused to understand it since Indonesia has more than 1000 ethnics. It's hard to make them understand it grammatically.

Comment: It's not an adverb. As @Ustanak correctly said, it's an auxiliary verb, and used to give emphasis to a positive verb. But I don't think it's used that way very often, unless the conversation leads someone to feel the need to introduce such emphasis – perhaps by suggesting something to the contrary first.

Comment: Yes, I know that now (like you explained and @Ustanak said). Explaining it to students (24 students with different ethnics and background) in one classroom is hard for me. Like I said above "I have to".

Answer (score 1):

1. *I **do** love her* is using *emphasis*. You can just say *I love her*, but by adding *do*, you make it emphatic. The meaning in this case is *Yes, I love her.*
2. *I **really** love her* it's kind of similar. The adverb is used along with the verb to say how something happens. The meaning is like *I'm in loved.*

Comment: If `really` is an adverb, so what the `do` is (in that context)?

Comment: It's the auxiliary just used to make the sentence emphatic.

Comment: As far as I can see that, An auxiliary is `to help` - help to `build` a certain sentence pattern.

Comment: I also see that `really` is to emphasize `how something happens too` (like you said)